# Symfony 3 service dependencie

Tags: service, dependencies, symfony

I try to create a service using symfony 3.
I copied an existing service file  I did on an old Symfony2 version.

```
services:
    agora.accessService:
        class: Agora\APIBundle\Services\AccessService
        scope: request
        arguments: ['@request', '@logger', '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', '@session']
```

The problem is I want to inject the request as a param to the constructor. It used to work on the older version but now I have this error :

`The service "agora.accessservice" has a dependency on a non-existent service "request".`

Of course on my service class I have added `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;`

Comment: I should have searched a little more. I found a working solution which consists on injecting request stack instead of request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
services:
    agora.accessService:
        class: Agora\APIBundle\Services\AccessService
        scope: request
        arguments: ['@request_stack', '@logger', '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', '@session']
```

I've injected request stack instead of request. That works fine.

```
public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, ...)
{
    $this->_request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
}
```

Comment: Be careful.  For many services (especially tagged services) the service might be created before the request is even available.  Better to store the request stack then pull the request when you actually need it.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed since [Symfony 2.4](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack) you have to inject `request_stack` service instead request service

Answer (score -2):

Since **2017 and Symfony 3.3+** this is very simple:

#### 1. Register services with autowiring via [PSR-4 service autodiscovery](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/#4-use-psr-4-based-service-autodiscovery-and-registration)

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    Agora\:
       resource: ../../src/Agora
```

#### 2. Require `RequestStack` in service via Constructor Injection

```
<?php

namespace Agora\APIBundle\Services;

class AccessService
{
    /**
     * @var AnotherService 
     */
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $anotherService, LoggerInterface etc.)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can found similar answer, that **extra explains how to get `Request` in Controller**, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46867521/1348344

Comment: Ok, thanks for your notes. Will do. I answered similar questions in more broad way before, but I was warned not to duplicate those answers, that's why I kept it short here.

Comment: Done! Could I get feedback for the downvotes after this edit? In case they're outdated.

Comment: Not my downvotes (I generally only flag stuff like this). A lot of people drive-by downvote link-only answers

Comment: Incidentally, it's not considered kosher to answer a question and then vote to close. Not something they'll ban you for, just frowned upon

Comment: I see. Why do you think it was in such order? I suggested duplicate, but after no response for couple of hours I've decided to answer. Rather then to keep question with old answers for uncertain amount of time.

Comment: Closure isn't something that happens quickly, most of the time (if you get 1000 points in a tag you can dupe them by yourself). But we have a [chat room for closing things](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) if you want to help speed things along

Comment: I see. I'm giving SO way too much time lately, so I need some cooldown. Thanks for your tips and know-how.